Trying to identify this cannondale road bike!
Need help identifying this bike thanks! 

I think Criggie narrowed it down as best as can be done with the limited information provided.  More details, especially of the drivetrain would likely help more.

From the hood shape and the blur markings, could be Shimano 105 (5800), or else the same generation of Ultegra. Crankset was down-specced. The wheels are possibly an upgrade from stock; those are Mavics with carbon fairings, so the black brake track is more likely to be PEO-coated aluminum rather than carbon (if carbon track, why would you use a non-structural fairing).

Is there something specific you're looking for, beyond "Cannondale Evo" as written on the frame and fork?
It could be an Evo 6, 4, 3, or 2 - there's really not a lot of visual difference between them.
As for year, it could be 2017 through 2019 - the seat stays are not dropped like the current model.
Here's the 2019 spec for a super-six evo, found from a search engine   https://99spokes.com/en-NZ/bikes/cannondale/2019/supersix-evo-ultegra
You can compare the components to see how close this was - your photo shows the "wrong" side of the bike because the transmission is mostly obscured.

Visually, the levers look like the 5800/6800 generation of Shimano. The wheels are also likely not a 2017-era item. Mavic may have been out of contention by then.

It's actually a 2014/2015 model. That fit the timeline a little better?

See the lettering on the back of the seat tube? SST? SuperSix Team model. Specifically a Cannondale Evo Himod Team.
